# how to make server call whenever device screen is turned ON without Service

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

This requirement is only satisfied if the app is running in the background.And if the Screen is turned on if the user presses to check any notifications then an Asynctask is called if the app is running in the background and makes a call to the server.

I have tried using Broadcast Receiver when screen on and tried to execute, it works only if the app is on the front screen after pressing the home button .And then if the user presses Power button after an hour then nothing happens .

Basically I am not sure if the app is being killed after sometime when in background. Please help me.I am a noob in Android and this functionality is something I thought most of the developers might be using but I did not see anything except service calls and I really did not want any service/alarm-manager as I don't want it to work continuously.

TIA

Comment: try registering the broadcast reciver in the manifest instead of from code ;)

Comment: Thank you Sir.I will try that and let you know how it goes. ANy other suggestion or link which is working and satisfies the above requirement.Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to make server call whenever device screen is turned ON without Service

This is not possible. `ACTION_SCREEN_ON` is a broadcast that can only be received by a `BroadcastReceiver` registered via `registerReceiver()`. So, unless you are the foreground activity, the only way you can receive this broadcast is via an always-running service, which is not a good idea.

> as I don't want it to work continuously

Then do not "make server call whenever device screen is turned ON". Find some other solution for whatever business problem you have that you are trying to solve this way.

Comment: Thank you Sir using the broadcast receiver for now.